# How to handle descrepencies between develop and main branches of Terraform project

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, terraform, branch

There are main and develop branches in TF project.
In develop branch, there could be resources specified with IDs which are dependent on AWS environment, e.g. `2c289348-cc9d-41ed-a4ae-fb015b0ec9b1-6` is AWS MSK cluster id:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "msk-admin-policy" {
  name        = "msk-admin-policy"
  description = "Policy for MSK"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {

        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          <...actions>
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:kafka:${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:cluster/integrations/2c289348-cc9d-41ed-a4ae-fb015b0ec9b1-6",
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

In main branch, there is different AWS MSK id which stands for id of AWS MSK cluster in production AWS environment.

It leads us to manage `develop` and `main` branches separately, meaning that we are not able to do a marge request from develop to main. Instead, we are creating a feature branch from develop, then create a merge request from a feature branch to `develop`. Then we create feature branch from main, create a merge request from a feature branch to `main`

As you can see, we have applied kind of unification between branches for region and account id by `${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}`.

Is there an approach to handle such kind of discrepencies between main and develop branches in TF?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Branching strategy and CI/CD pipeline for a Terraform project with multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056020/branching-strategy-and-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-terraform-project-with-multiple-envi)

Comment: So the only difference is the last part of the ARN, i.e., `2c289348....`?

Comment: if you have created that resource in the same code base , then I would say just reference the arn of that resource in the resources section . If the resource was created in a different workspace ie. different repo from the one you have been using , then you could add tags on the resource that are can be deterministic between branches and fetch the resource using a data source and then reference the arn of that datasource . Otherwise , you could create a variable could cluster_arn and pass it as a value between workspaces , either of those will work and resolve your merging problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be hard-coding those values at all, you should be referencing the Terraform resource, or looking up the datasource. If you absolutely have to hard-code the value, then I recommend hard-coding it in a Terraform map variable, like:

```
variable "msk_id" {
  description = "the MSK Cluster ID"

  type = map(string)
  default = {
    dev: "2c289348-cc9d-41ed-a4ae-fb015b0ec9b1-6"
    production : "some-other-id"
  }
}
```

Then you could pass the environment name as another variable, or ideally use [Terraform Workspaces](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/workspaces) to manage your different environments.

Then your IAM policy would look like this (with the environment name in a var):

```
"Resource": [
  "arn:aws:kafka:${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:cluster/integrations/${var.msk_id[var.environment]}",
]
```

or (with Terraform workspaces):

```
"Resource": [
  "arn:aws:kafka:${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:cluster/integrations/${var.msk_id[terraform.workspace]}",
]
```