# Terraform modules CI/CD for multiple environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws, cicd

I've built a full infrastructure for our team using Terraform which is working well. The solution is based on terraform modules, this is our structure at the moment

```
modules
  eks
    eks.tf
    variables.tf
  lambda
    lambda.tf
    variables.tf
  s3
    s3.tf
    variables.tf
staging
  eks
    eks.tf
  lambda
    lambda.tf
  s3
    s3.tf
    ...
```

Basically what we do is we get for each service what we have defined under modules and then we reference said module under example staging/s3/s3.tf and we deploy the service from there.

What I want to achieve is we're using gitlab and I want to have a CI/CD process for this because right now I'm just running infra changes from locally.

The idea would be to deploy each service for staging separately via CI/CD so I would have to change directory and go into staging/eks for example before deploying changes. I just have no idea how to do that right now. I'm looking for pointers to where should I even start.

At the moment what I do is I cd into staging/lambda for example. I run terraform init, I run terraform plan and then I do terraform apply which deploys if there's changes. I'm just looking to replicate this to gitlab ci/cd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Branching strategy and CI/CD pipeline for a Terraform project with multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056020/branching-strategy-and-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-terraform-project-with-multiple-envi)

Comment: That does seem like a good option. I will give it a try doing a branch based CI/CD. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use Terragrunt for building infrastructure for multiple environments. You can find more details here:
https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-multiple-environments-with-terraform-using-terragrunt-2c3e32fc60a8

This can be achieved without terragrunt as well, but requires a bit more effort in setting up and providing inputs.

Comment: I've actually gone with terragrunt since dealing with multi environments appeared to be quite a hassle with my structure and it works great. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which ci/cd you are using, you can configure the dev branch to run staging and the main branch to run production.

For GitLab you can try [this](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/02/05/ci-deployment-and-environments/)